# Opencart Admin Access: Invalid token session. Please login again

Tags: opencart

Version No.
Version 1.5.4

When I try to log into my admin account on this computer the error message "Invalid token session. Please login again." pops up, this error has been occurring since yesterday. On chrome this error stops me from even reseting the password. Trying out alternative browsers inlcuding one one my Tablet just returns the "No match for Username and/or Password." error.

How can I solve this issue? I have looked in my MYSQL and the databases seem fine, I also went into my PHPAdmin and changes the admin user to a default password string. I have not tried reinstalling the site yet as I assume I would need to add all the products and settings again.

Comment: Does this happen when you enter a username and password or just when you view the admin login screen?

Comment: Resetting your password through phpMyAdmin should work. Just don't forget to apply md5 encryption to it.

Comment: @Jay Gildford The error happens when I enter Username and Password. I can access the login screen, just not the dashboard.

@ B-and-P I have tried entering the password string in phpMyAdmin and I still cannot access the admin dashboard.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a simple fix to see if this is more than just human error. Open

```
system/library/user.php
```

Search for this code

```
user WHERE username
```

replace it with

```
user #WHERE username
```

and save. This essentially disables user/password checking and will load the first user in your `user` table. Simply click login on your admin interface then with anything/nothing in the user/password fields and if it doesn't log in, you have an issue more than just human error

## DONT FORGET TO REVERT YOUR USER.PHP FILE ONCE YOU'VE CHECKED IT

Comment: Thanks, I tried this and I managed to access the admin account. I also replaced the code so everything seems to be working.

Comment: In that case, it was likely a problem with the username/password pair. be sure to reset your details in the admin while logged in

Comment: there is no user.php under system/librarym :( my version 2.2

Comment: @Geniusintrouble it's system/library/cart/user.php in later versions

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by changing my browser's ad blocker.

Answer (score 0):

session id problem
please go database open oc_session table and field session_id set "Uniqe" then issue
solved.
like see image attachment[image]