# Not able to login in OpenCart, it shows invalid token session error

Tags: php, opencart

My OpenCart 3.0.2 website worked fine until few days ago. Now when I log in it says "Invalid token session. Please login again.", and is not letting me get through the log in page. Please answer this question if youy have a solution or workaround, I'm ready to change the core PHP files also if nothing works.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z7v4u.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Opencart Admin Access: Invalid token session. Please login again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16506897/opencart-admin-access-invalid-token-session-please-login-again)

Comment: That answer is for a very old version. My version is 3.0.2

Comment: Did you try forgot password?

Comment: Does it work properly, when you try in a Private Browser window?

Comment: Have you recently installed any plugins it extensions?